# What is wrong with my jquery validate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, entity-framework-4, jquery-validate

I came upon the strangest situation so far. I have a form that has two textboxes. I also have buttons that belong to three different classes such as .addTopTenFav , .addCurrentFav , .addOther. I have added validation logic and attributes to my Entity model, and it works as expected for two of my buttons. That is when I click a particular button I do something like myform.validate().Form(); and then I check  if ($("#myform").valid()) so in two of my poartial views the form is validated, no error messages appear and it's all good. BUT for some strange reason when I click the .addOtherSong button the if statement that checks if my form is valid goes to the else part where i put a simple alert box. No error messages appear, i double check what i type into the textboxes... and of course... somehow the form is not valid while clicking the other buttons the form is valid.

But there's more, so i try to debug this, in google's chrome browser I use the console and i type in something like $("#myform").validate().element( "#myselect" ); to check each textbox one by one, and it returns true for both of them meaning that my input is validated and passes the test, but when I run the app and I click on my add button the form is not Valid, what is wrong?

```
 $(function () {

    $(document).on("click", ".btnAddSongTilesToGenre", function (e) {
        var name = $('#youTubeNameTxt').val();
        var link = $('#youTubeLinkTxt').val();
        var len = link.length;
        var substr = link.substr(31, len - 31);
        var container = $(this).parent().parent().find(".actualTilesContainer");
        $(container).slideDown();
        var genreId = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#hiddenRank").val(genreId);

        $("#AddTopTenFavForm").validate().form();

        if ($("#AddTopTenFavForm").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () { ShowAjaxLoader(); },
                url: "/Home/AddSong",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(),
                success: function (data) { HideAjaxLoader(), ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"), $(container).find('ul').append('<li><a class="savedLinks" href="#" name="' + substr + '" >' + name + '</a> <span name= ' + data + ' class="btnDeleteSong dontDoAnything">x</span></li>'); },
                error: function () { HideAjaxLoader(), ShowMsg("Song could not be added, please try again") }
            });
            $('#youTubeLinkTxt').val('');
            $('#youTubeNameTxt').val('');

        }
        else {
            alert("notValid");
        }

        if ($(e.target).hasClass("dontDoAnything")) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#otherFavContainer").on("click", ".songTilesGenreContainer", function (e) {
        var myVar = $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer");

        if ($(myVar).hasClass("minimalized")) {
            $(myVar).removeClass("minimalized").addClass("maximized").slideDown();
        }
        else {
            $(myVar).removeClass("maximized").addClass("minimalized").slideUp();
        }

    });
```

my validation attributes

```
namespace yplaylist.Models
{
  [MetadataType(typeof(TopTenFav_Validation))]
  public partial class TopTenFav
  {
  }

  public class TopTenFav_Validation
  {
    [RegularExpression("http://www.youtube.com/watch\\?v=.*", ErrorMessage = "Youtube Link must begin with: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v= ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Youtube link is Required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Song Title cannot exceed 100 characters")]
    public string YoutubeLink { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Youtube link cannot exceed 100 characters")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Song title is Required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Youtube link may begin with http://youtu.be

Comment: the thing is its not about what i type in the textboxes, why it works for the other buttons but for this one it doesnt]

Comment: `$("#AddTopTenFavForm").validate()` needs to be inside the DOM ready and **not** inside a `click` handler.  `.validate()` initializes the validation and it only needs to happen _once_.  Simply use `.valid()` ret-rigger a test of the form's validity.  Question is too old and too localized to post a specific answer.